# Running external commands from a Custom GUI in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, perl, cmd

for one of my applications, I am trying to send/receive commands/information from my GUI application to the cmd window.

There is one problem however.. I also have a perl installation which I need to work with. the problem is when I try perl -v in the cmd window the cmd window reacts with the perl version message. When i try it my GUI it comes up with the message

'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please suggest..

**Update**

Restarting my machine solved that issue. I really dont know what was the issue with the path variables..

**New Question, Please**

I have a sample perl script that waits for a user response and then starts acting on the input provided. It behaves as it should in the cmd window., but when it comes to my GUI.. it does not wait for the user input.. There is an endless looop and it keeps on printing the message to my UI..

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks and Regards
Gagan Janjua

Comment: Perhaps you should give the full path to the perl executable.  Sounds like your program has a different PATH set up than your cmd window.

Comment: have you tried to specify the full path and working directory?

Comment: Nope.. I have not set the path anywhere.. in my cmd window .. however I will try with the full Perl compiler path.. but this is indeed bizzare to say the least

Comment: Checked it.. when i go to the perl folder and execute the perl -v command it runs fine.. thats expected.. but why does it not run when I am in any other folder.. since the path to the perl compiler has been defined in the Environment Variables

Comment: @Gagan: use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question (and do include some minimal example C# and Perl that illustrates the problem). For the original question, either close it or put your "Restarting my machine solved that issue" as an Answer in the "Answer your Question" section below, then wait a few days and accept it by clicking the tick icon (though personally I doubt the Q+A will be useful to other people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my application seems to have fixed my issue...

thanks @RedGrittyBrick.. I will remember the tip...